# Tkinter - Get the name and value of scale/slider

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the name of the scale/slider when the scale/slider value changes. I've managed to get the value of scale by using:

```
self.slider = tk.Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=100, 
                           orient="horizontal")
        self.slider.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.updateValue)
```

and:

`def updateValue(self, event):
        print self.slider.getName()`

I would like to do it like it's done in java, something like:

```
JSlider object = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
```

So that I could get the name and value of the scale.
Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Just to clarify: You are planning to attach the same callback command to multiple sliders and want to get the slider that was used from the `event`?

Comment: @tobias_k yes  so it can get the name and value of each slider

Comment: @tobias_k thanks, do u think i could just make a string for each slider and use that as the name like: scale1 = "ScaleName".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by name? Do you want to get `self.slider` back? Because to be honest that doesn't really make much sense. Multiple names can point to the same object, so each object should keep a list of all names that are assigned to it, which they don't. A variable name is a one-way reference to an object.

Comment: @fhdrsdg i'd done something similar in java before where if u use JSlider object = (JSlider) evt.getSource(); you can then use the methods object.getName() and object.getValue() and i meant if there was a similar way to do this in python. There was using label and widget

Comment: There are multiple ways to identify different widgets, but getting the variable name just isn't one of them, that's all I'm trying to say. You could even do `self.slider.name = 'Slider 1'` and in the callback get `event.widget.name`. That way you aren't forced to display a label at the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `widget` from the [`event`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/events.html), check whether it's a `Scale` and get the value with `get()`. To get the name of the widget, use `cget("label")` (assuming that by "name" you meant the scale's label). Something like this:

```
def updateValue(self, event):
    w = event.widget
    if isinstance(w, tk.Scale):
        print repr(w)
        print w.get()
        print w.cget("label")
```

Usage like this (same as in your code, but with added `label` parameter):

```
self.slider = tk.Scale(self.root, label="First Slider", from_=0, to=100, orient="horizontal")
self.slider.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.updateValue)
```

Note, however, that this only works with `bind`, not with the `command` parameter, as a `command` callback does not get the `Event` but just the new value as a parameter. Also, this only works with `Tkinter.Scale`, not with `ttk.Scale` as the latter has no `label` parameter.

Comment: @tobais_k thanks a lot, shame about the name though.

Comment: @Rob177 You can use the `Scale`s `label` attribute for that. Confused it with `ttk.Scale`, which does not have one.