# How to get scale value with button press tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, get, slider

I really did my best to find the solution on my own, but haven't. I want to have the value from a slider and then save it to a csv file (which is working fine), at the click of a button. Alas, I can't get the value of the `tkinter.Scale` during my button event. I wonder if it global variables might solve my problem, but I haven't gotten them to work. I'm particularly surprised because I can print a live stream of the scale's value as I change it, but can't save it in a useful way. If you could answer any of my befuddlement or let me know if my question is unclear or in anyway could be better, I'd greatly appreciate it. Here are some links to things that helped me get this far:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables

[Tkinter - Get the name and value of scale/slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208566/tkinter-get-the-name-and-value-of-scale-slider)

Here is my attempt to print the final value 10 times:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def scaleevent(v):    #Live update of value printed to shell
    print(v)
    variable = v

def savevalue():
    global variable              #This is what I want to work, but doesn't
    for i in range(10):
        print(variable)

scale = Scale(orient='vertical', command=scaleevent).grid(column=0,row=0)
button = Button(text="button", command=savevalue).grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

And here is my attempt to solve my problem using `.get()`:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def savevalue():        #print value 10 times. In final version I will save it instead
    for i in range(10):
        print(scale.get())     #I really want this to work, but it doesn't,
    root.destroy               #is it because .get is in a function?

scale = Scale(orient='vertical', command=scaleevent).grid(column=0,row=0)
button = Button(text="button", command=savevalue).grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

(Python 3.5, Windows 10)

Edit:

This is the error I get from the first attempt using a global variable:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\programing\tkinter scale question.py", line 15, in savevalue
    print(variable)
NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

That's what happened when I run the first example of code, and similarly my actual project. Thanks Bryan Oakley!

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error? Please post the error.

Comment: There are better ways to do this task, but a simple fix for your 1st code example is to move that `global variable` directive from `savevalue` to `scaleevent`.

Comment: In your first snippet, you need to move the `global variable` declaration to the `scaleevent()` function because otherwise it's just a local variable there—so it's never defined when `savevalue()` is called since all that function does is attempt to read the variable's current value.

Comment: It worked!! Than you PM 2Ring and martineau, I glad it was that simple. I'd love to know what other ways to do this, but I'm pumped that this worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks marineau, that does look better.

Comment: I see common mistake `var = Widget(...).grid(...)` - it assigns `None` to `var` because `grid()/pack()/place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines: `var = Widget(...)` and  `var.grid(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `global` in `scaleevent` because you try to assing value to `variable`. Without `global` it assigns `v` to local `variable` and then it doesn't exists in `savevalue`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def scaleevent(v):
    global variable

    print(v)
    variable = v

def savevalue():
    print(variable)

Scale(orient='vertical', command=scaleevent).grid(column=0,row=0)
Button(text="button", command=savevalue).grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

As for second version you made mistake with `var = Widget(...).grid()`

It assigns `None` to `var` because `grid()/pack()/place()` returns `None`.
You have to do it in two lines:

```
var = Widget(...)
var.grid(...)
```

Code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def savevalue():
    print(scale.get())
    root.destroy() # you forgot ()

scale = Scale(orient='vertical')
scale.grid(column=0,row=0)

button = Button(text="button", command=savevalue)
button.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

from tkinter import *

```
root = Tk()
variable=0 # only you forgot this 
def scaleevent(v):
    print(v)
    global variable

    variable=v

def savevalue():
    print(variable)

Scale(orient='vertical', command=scaleevent).grid(column=0,row=0)
Button(text="button", command=savevalue).grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```